# PWM drivers of Shift registers that are not open drain?

Tags: pwm, driver, shift-register, open-drain

I am need of a 16 channel PWM Serial based LED driver, or serial in – parallel out shiftregister. I had been looking at [TLC5940](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc5940.pdf) and [TLC59025](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc59025.pdf) respectively.

But for my current set up the ouptuts cannot be open drain, the output of each channel needs to be +5v 10mA, to switch a transistor. The TLC5940 approach would probably be better than the soft pwm approach with the TLC59025.

Does anything like this exist? if not what other approach would I take?

The individual LED driver circuits shown below:

[image]

Comment: pull-up resistors? PNP transistors?

Comment: I am hoping to keep part count very low - so if there was something that could help this, its preferred.

Comment: I'm guessing you can't change the wiring because your parts are common cathode (e.g. 7-segment display)?

Comment: Yeah my led boards are in production, based on the circuit on page 5 of http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/NSI50350AS-D.PDF these will be linked back to controller board (working on now)

Comment: Can you include a simplified schematic of your LED board? Depending on how it's driven, maybe there are more clever tricks to be made.

Comment: @Phil Frost, see above. These circuits are all ready made and connected to the controller via cabling.

Comment: @davivid thanks. Well, if you can't change that board I don't have any more clever ideas. You will have to consider that R4 in your schematic and R2 in my schematic will both reduce the base current to Q2. Probably looking for a 4000 CMOS series IC that does what you need will be lower power, cheaper, and less parts than either of my solutions.

Comment: @Phil Frost, could I just set R2 to 1K and solder bridge R4?

Comment: @davivid you could, but if re-working the LED boards is fair game, you could stuff a PNP in for Q2 and get rid of even more components, while keeping the same PCBs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could add pull-up resistors. If you need a lot, they are available in a SIL package which will reduce your part count:

[image: pull-up resistors]

But here's even less parts, if you can use a PNP transistor to switch the LED:

[image: PNP emitter follower]

And, you can still use a SIL resistor package for R1. Also, Q1 does not saturate, which may make your PWM control easier, if your PWM frequency is high!

Comment: Unfortunately the high power constant current LED boards are separate from the controller (working on now) and have already been sent off and use an NPN: http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/NSS40201L-D.PDF. I didn't think about resistors in a SIL package - could be a good compromise! Or maybe I could just replace the transistor in this edition. Thanks.

Comment: @davivid In that case, I bet there's a [CMOS 4000 series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_4000_series_integrated_circuits) IC that can do what you want, and doesn't require a pull-up resistor. They can't sink as much current, but your driver probably doesn't need it.

Comment: @davivid looking at this again, R4 was unnecessary. See edit.

Comment: So it will invert the logic of the output? eg when the open collector output is off, D2 will be lit, when the open collector output is on, D2 will be off?

Comment: @davivid It's true that when the open collector output is on (it's actively sinking current) that the LED will be off. But, this may be considered a logic _false_, since the output is low, so maybe it's not inverting, depending on how you define your logic.